# How could this differential equation be solved (hint, method)?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$Ay''+B(y')^n+C=0$$
$n \in\mathbb N$, $A,B,C \in\mathbb R$

I tried to substitute $y'=f$, then

$Af'+Bf^n+C=0$, then for $A\neq 0$

$f'=-bf^n-c$, where $b=B/A$ and $c=C/A$.

I don't quite know how to manipulate with the $n$ power of the function.

Comment: You are really asking about integrating $\frac{1}{b}\int \frac{dx}{x^n- d}$ where $d= \frac{c}{b}$.  You would do that by factoring $x^n- d$ into linear and quadratic terms, using "partial fractions" to write the integrand as a sum of fractions with linear and quadratic denominators and then integrating each.

Comment: 6 minutes. $ $ $ $

Comment: Is it possible to do the factorization for n and integrate the all of then in general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation in $f$ is separable:
$$
\frac{A\,f'}{B\,f^n+C}=-1,\quad \int\frac{A\,df}{B\,f^n+C}=-x+C.
$$
Now you have to do:

1. Carry out the integration.
2. Solve for $f$ as a function of $x$.
3. Integrate $f$ to find $y$.

Except for special values of $n$, it will be almost impossible to get an explicit solution.

Answer (score 0):

$$Ay''+B(y')^n+C=0$$
$$Az'+Bz^n+C=0$$
$$-\frac AB\int \frac {dz}{z^n+C/B}=\int dx$$
$$\int \frac {dz}{z^n+C/B}=-\frac BAx+K$$
Now integration depends on the value of n

For $n=2$ it's pretty easy..